Extract content from Notepad++
Hi I am trying to extract mcc and mnc along with their values from a log file defined under "userLocationinfo: class UserLocation{" Can anyone help with that? The overall file is big and lot of other content but I just want to extract mcc and mnc defined under userLocation function.
Moreover this userLocationinfo can repeat in my overall log file so I want to extract all the entries.
    userLocationinfo: class UserLocation {
        eutraLocation: class EutraLocation {
            tai: class Tai {
                plmnId: class PlmnId {
                    mcc: 641
                    mnc: 10
                }
                tac: 0023
                nid: null
            }
            ignoreTai: false
            ecgi: class Ecgi {
                plmnId: class PlmnId {
                    mcc: 641
                    mnc: 10
                }
                eutraCellId: 0085405
                nid: null
            }
            ignoreEcgi: false
            ageOfLocationInformation: null
            ueLocationTimestamp: null
            geographicalInformation: null
            geodeticInformation: null
            globalNgenbId: null
            globalENbId: null
        }
        nrLocation: null
        n3gaLocation: null
        utraLocation: null
        geraLocation: null
    }

I am new to notepad++ regex so not aware of how to use it. I want below from "userLocationinfo: class UserLocation {"
mcc: 641
mnc: 10

mcc and mnc occur multiple times within the above block.  Do you want all matches?  Also, is the indentation in your file always consistent?
